# distorted output in python IDLE while using tabulate or texttable libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle, tabulate

I tried to print output in a nice table using texttable, code given below

```
from texttable import Texttable
t = Texttable()
t.add_rows([['Name', 'Age'], ['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]])
print(t.draw())
```

the code works fine and gives an output

but the output i got is;
[distorted output in IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fmGX.jpg)
how can i tackle this?

EDIT: Got the solution; change to monospaced font.(courier is a good choice)

Comment: Switch to a monospaced font

Comment: Command line consoles, such as Windows Command Prompt, usually only come with monospaced fonts.  IDLE allows one to select any font on your system that tk can access.  The default font is intended to be a monospaced.  If you did not change from the default, I am curious what system you have and what the default was.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy  I'm using windows and official python IDLE,(the colorful thing,shell? idk im a student),I'm positive I didnt change the font from default.

Comment: You would know if you did.  User customization is per user, so if no one else used that account, then we will have to leave this a mystery.